# How to remove "Code" from EOS?

Tags: software-installation

Title sums it all up.

How do I remove "Code" from Elementary.

Thus far I've been stymied.

Working on Horus.

Thanks

chris

Comment: I've tried uninstalling through the app center . It's goes through the motions but remains installed.

Just tried it again.

It toggles back and forth between Free and Open a couple of times and then the app center closes.

Borked....

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt remove io.elementary.code

Bug report submitted.